# Grep variable and loop over next column

Tags: r, bash

I have a big sorted data file in the format

```
car 54.9

car 33.2

car 29.7

Bike 96.1

Bike 94.6

Bike 80
```

I want fractional value compared to first value i.e. for each variable(car and bike) divide the number in second column by the highest number for that variable.
Desired output

```
car 1

car 0.6

car 0.54

Bike 1

Bike 0.98

Bike 0.83
```

I can grep the variables but how to loop over second column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk you could so something like this:

```
$ awk '$1!=l{l=$1;m=$2}{$2/=m}1' file
car 1
car 0.604736
car 0.540984
Bike 1
Bike 0.984391
Bike 0.832466
```

This requires that the file sorted first by column $1, and then by column $2, descending.

How this works? The input file is scanned line by line. The first term `$1!=l{l=$1;m=$2}` filters the lines where the first word is equal to variable `l`. If they are not found equal (which will happen in the first line of a block), the first word is stored in line `l` (so that we can identify where the next block begins. The second word is stored in variable `m`. Since this is the first line of a block, and the file is sorted, this is largest value for the block.

The next term `{$2/=m}` is executed for all lines (since it contains no filters), and replaces the second word with the division of the word by the max (which is stored in variable `m`).

The final block `1`, represents a true condition, with the default action, which is to print the current line, Thus all lines are printed.

Comment: can you explain it a bit

Comment: @Haroon: Sure, I made an edit. Let me know if anything is still unclear

Answer (score 3):

In `R`, we can use `data.table` (after reading the dataset by `read.table/read.csv` or `fread` from `data.table`).  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Col1', we divide the 'Col2' by the maximum value of 'Col2' and assign (`:=`) it back to 'Col2'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Col2 := round(Col2/max(Col2), 2) , by = Col1]
df1
#   Col1    Col2
#1:  car    1.00
#2:  car    0.60
#3:  car    0.54
#4: Bike    1.00
#5: Bike    0.98
#6: Bike    0.83
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("car", "car", "car", "Bike", "Bike", 
"Bike"), Col2 = c(54.9, 33.2, 29.7, 96.1, 94.6, 80)), .Names = c("Col1", 
"Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: @RHertel Thanks, i failed to notice the `highest`